Glyph origin of 㒼
I cannot seem to find any satisfactory explanations for this character, which doesn't seem to be used alone anymore, more as a phonetic component. Not sure if it's related to grass or 廿, or is it some sort of animal skin (has resemblance to 革). Is there any link to 滿 (full/covered with water)?

Earliest appearances seem to be mid-Western Zhou. If this character was first created in this period, I would decompose it as ⿱口㒳 in regular script; 口 based on samples of 黃 and 堇 around the same time, and definitely not 廿. A quick search only yields 㒼簋, where it is used as a person's name (黃賓㒼章一。馬兩。 -> 黃 gifted a jade ornament and 2 horses to 㒼), so not much help.

我看不懂繁体字。写简体中文的话我能理解。

@dROOOze 『說文解字』㒼 - 平也。从廿，五行之數，二十分爲一辰。㒳，㒼平也。讀若蠻。母官切 文三. https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E3%92%BC (hope this helps).

@r13 「㒼」字最早出現在西周的金文資料中，相關資料應包含「㒼」字的語音和意義，並保留該字的用法痕跡。應查找的是記載有「㒼」字的西周、春秋、戰國時期的出土文獻，而非秦漢時期的《說文解字》。

。。。。。。隋唐《集韻》、宋朝《廣韻》、傳世的俗字、大陸的簡化字等更不用提了、這些都跟西周時代字的字源無關。

Looked this character up and unfortunately, the origin of this glyph is unknown for now :(

Updates,
I've found a open access website of tracing back original glyph of 满. It includes glyph examples from 金文 and 篆文. The new finding almost takes over my mind, which is in contrast to my original answer.

㒼 is a hierioglyph that shares the same origin with 芇，繭 and 爾, varied in stroke complexity and side emphasis of meaning.

The website says the glyph 㒼in 金文 should be, although not clearly being observed, derives from 爾 in 甲骨文. Its meaning should also be originated from 爾, which is silkworm spinning cocoon. 㒼's meaning in 金文 remains, as well as extending to covering up totally (see 滿/瞞/蟎/顢), then extending to average/equivalent afterwards, then becoming a phonetic component only till now.
As for the annotation as the decomposition by 廿 and 㒳, just drawing a forced analogy by the offspring, who may as confused as me.
Correct me if the answer misleading!
Original answer
One of variants of 㒼A is 䓣B. They are very alike in writing, the only difference is the length of 一 below 艹/艸, where A (your posts) is shorter than B. A is recorded in 《廣韻》 while B in 《集韻．上聲．養韻》. Since they are recorded from different books I'm not sure which one of A, B is the origin, regardless of other variants like C, D, E. But 《字鑑》 says some variants are 俗/common social habit, some are wrong written (see the bottom).
So I give up finding the original glyph. The only thing I can do is to focus on the explanation of A in 《廣韻》, 㒼 is composed of 廿 and 㒳,

平也。从廿，五行之數，二十分爲一辰；㒳，㒼平也。讀若蠻，母官切。

which I can't translate precisely. I'm actually confused by the expression of 㒳，㒼平也。, it seems that 㒳 describe the status where 㒼 is reached, but isn't it a circular argument?
I also think this question highly related to the one on Zhihu, where @momo's answer , which includes examples of 金文, is good enough to me, but might be inaccessible. Because you must register on the website before watching the full answer :-(.
Considering the fact that lots of variants of 滿 exist in history (see the bottom), and 㒼 roles as a phonetic component, I'm not fully confident about my answer, just summarizing my searching result.

According from 滿 - 教育部《異體字字典》,
there are ↓many variants of the character 滿. My observation is that the glyph in Traditional Chinese varies from A(氵廿㒳) while in Simplified Chinese from B(氵艹两).

and ↓ the character 㒼 roles as a phonetic component.

↓ 㒼's annotation in 《字鑑》,


Is there any way to fold part of my post, like folding the picture? It looks too long now.

May be you can use https://www.imgur.com/

『說文解字注』(㒼)平也。廣韵曰：無穿孔狀。按周禮鼈人：掌取互物。注云：互物謂有甲䓣胡，龜鼈之屬。从廿。二十倂也。五行之數，二十分爲一辰。此說从廿之意。五行，每行得卄分，分之適平。其法未聞。从㒳。从字今補。㒳、各本作㒼。誤，今正。平也。此說从㒳之意。讀若蠻。母官切。十四部。(hope this helps). https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E3%92%BC

@zrsammy I changed your last picture size. You can use this one https://imgse.com/i/pAs7xbV

@Tom many thanks, but I think image hosting is not a good choice for stability. I have to decline your edit.

@zrsammy OK, I see. It doesn't matter.

We are not sure of the origin of this character.  Its original meaning seems to be something like "balanced, even."  Its use in 滿 is probably both phonetic and also an extension of meaning where the level of the water becomes even with the rim of its container, leading to the meanings "filled; satisfied; complacent."
If 㒼 shares an origin with 兩, then it might represent two balanced cows or horses pulling evenly.  The character 兩 may have an origin as two 丙 (indicating a horse or chariot) written together. The top part of 㒼 might be the bridle or some sort of crosspiece that gives the pulling idea.
